# How to get my current location with HERE maps api

Tags: geolocation, maps, coordinates

how do I get my current location on the HERE maps api?

I want to enable the geolocation of my current location and plugin the coordinates to this method 
map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});

Below is the code of the HERE maps to get location of a map which I got it from their website
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/maps/map-at-specified-location

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />
  <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >

/**
 * Moves the map to display over Berlin
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function moveMapToBerlin(map){
  map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
  map.setZoom(14);
}





/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'devportal-demo-20180625',
  app_code: '9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ',
  useHTTPS: true
});
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
  tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
  ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
});

//Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map, {pixelRatio: pixelRatio});

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
moveMapToBerlin(map);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

You may obtain your current lat long, and set it a variable, and replace

```
function moveMapToBerlin(map){
  map.setCenter({lat: xlat, lng: xlng});
  map.setZoom(14);
}
```